# How to process URL without specifying parameters

Tags: php, url, process, parameters

I was wondering if I could process an URL without specifing parameters. For example:
`http://www.example.com/Sometext_I_want_to_process`

I don't want to use: `http://www.example.com/index.php?text=Sometext_I_want_to_process`

The site has to redirect to a different page after processing.

What language choice do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using apache's mod_rewrite (similar functionality is found on other webservers) to rewrite the URL so that it is a parameter.  For instance with the text parameter you use, you could use the following mod_rewrite rules to get the parameter.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico # Want favicon.ico to work properly
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?text=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then you simply access the parameter in the script like you normally would.

```
<?php     
$stuff = $_GET['text'];
// Process $stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that kind of thing using Apache's [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

*Obvisouly, it means it must be enabled -- which is too often not the case by default.*

For instance, on a website, I use this in a [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?hash=$1   [L]
```

This redirects everything, like `www.mysite.com/152` to `www.mysite.com/index.php?hash=152`

And, then, in my PHP code, I can just use `$_GET` :

```
if (isset($_GET['hash'])) {
    if (is_numeric($_GET['hash'])) {
        // Use intval($_GET['hash']) -- I except an integer, in this application
    }
}
```

In your case, you'll probably want to replace "`hash`" by "`text`", but this should already help you getting closer to the solution ;-)